# Spring @Scheduled fixedDelay does not work as expected

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule my job in this way:
1) only one thread runs it. (serial)
2) with fixed interval between two runs

I use `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)` above my method and `<task:annotation-driven/>` in my applicationContext.xml. But according to my printed info, the interval between two jobs is not 10000ms as I set. Why is that?

```
19:07-25 22:38:46.190 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457526190
20:07-25 22:38:48.191 INFO  schedule:45 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] use 2000ms
21:07-25 22:38:48.191 INFO  schedule:47 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is finished.  ----->   1469457528191
25:07-25 22:39:03.198 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457543198
26:07-25 22:39:05.201 INFO  schedule:45 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] use 2002ms
27:07-25 22:39:05.202 INFO  schedule:47 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is finished.  ----->   1469457545202
31:07-25 22:39:20.205 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457560205
32:07-25 22:39:22.209 INFO  schedule:45 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] use 2004ms
33:07-25 22:39:22.210 INFO  schedule:47 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is finished.  ----->   1469457562210
37:07-25 22:39:37.213 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457577213
38:07-25 22:39:39.215 INFO  schedule:45 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] use 2002ms
39:07-25 22:39:39.215 INFO  schedule:47 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is finished.  ----->   1469457579215
43:07-25 22:39:54.221 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457594221
44:07-25 22:39:56.225 INFO  schedule:45 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] use 2004ms
45:07-25 22:39:56.225 INFO  schedule:47 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is finished.  ----->   1469457596225
49:07-25 22:40:11.525 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457611525
50:07-25 22:40:13.528 INFO  schedule:45 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] use 2003ms
51:07-25 22:40:13.529 INFO  schedule:47 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is finished.  ----->   1469457613529
55:07-25 22:40:28.237 INFO  schedule:33 [21-thread-1] - [job#1] is running.   ----->   1469457628237
```

you can see the time between finished and running is not 10000ms. (more like 15000)

the code is (spring 4.2.1):

```
   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void timerJob1(){
        SCHEDULER.info("[job#1] is running.   ----->   {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            long use = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            SCHEDULER.info("[timeJob1] use {}ms", use);
        }

        long use = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        SCHEDULER.info("[job#1] use {}ms", use);

        SCHEDULER.info("[job#1] is finished.  ----->   {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

Comment: I am seeing the exact same problem. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

You may have contention on the thread pool being used. Create your own executor to handle these fixed delay tasks by implementing and wiring the ScheduledConfigurer.

In your implementation of configureTasks() set your own Executor as a scheduler on the method parameter ScheduledTaskRegistrar.